# com.google.gson.JsonIOException: JSON document was not fully consumed in Android Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, slim

There are couple of questions already available about "JSON document was not fully consumed" in Stackoverflow, but there is no accepted answer. Link is given below.

[Android Retrofit 2.0 JSON document was not fully consumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386250/android-retrofit-2-0-json-document-was-not-fully-consumed)

[Why is JSON document not fully consumed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48322357/why-is-json-document-not-fully-consumed)

In my app I'm taking an email from user. And using my API, I'm checking given email is exist or not in the database. If exist, I'm sending a code to that email. I am using localhost as Server and have used Slim for API. I think my API is Ok. I checked it via Postman. The Json response that I shared in my post is from Postman. Actually I am learning Retrofit. Help please. Thanks in advance.

**RetrofitClient.java**

```
package com.example.royta.retrofitdemo.APIs;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://aa561878.ngrok.io/MyApi/public/";
    private static RetrofitClient retrofitClient;
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    private RetrofitClient() {

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }

    public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance() {
        if(retrofitClient == null) {
            retrofitClient = new RetrofitClient();
        }
        return retrofitClient;
    }

    public Api getApi() {
        return retrofit.create(Api.class);
    }
}
```

**Json**

```
{
    "isSend": true,
    "code": 117482,
    "email": true
}
```

**UserExist.java (Pojo)**

```
package com.example.royta.retrofitdemo.ModelClass;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class UserExist {
    @SerializedName("email")
    private boolean email;
    @SerializedName("isSend")
    private boolean isSend;
    @SerializedName("code")
    private int code;

    public UserExist(boolean email, boolean isSend, int code) {
        this.email = email;
        this.isSend = isSend;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public boolean isSend() {
        return isSend;
    }

    public boolean isEmailExist() {
        return email;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

**Api.java**

```
package com.example.royta.retrofitdemo.APIs;

import com.example.royta.retrofitdemo.ModelClass.UserExist;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface Api {

    @GET("finduser")
    Call<UserExist> isUserExist(
            @Query("email") String email

    );
}
```

Here is the call

```
        Call <UserExist> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().isUserExist(email);    
        call.enqueue(new Callback<UserExist>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserExist> call, Response<UserExist> response) {
                if(response.body().isEmailExist()) {

                    String resetCode = String.valueOf(response.body().getCode());
                    Log.d("ROYs", "Reset Code: "+resetCode);
                    Intent i = new Intent(FindAccount.this, EnterSecurityCode.class);
                    i.putExtra("email", email);
                    i.putExtra("code", resetCode);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else {

                    Toast.makeText(FindAccount.this, "You are not registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserExist> call, Throwable t) {
                String stacktrace = Log.getStackTraceString(t);
                Log.d("ROYs", "onFailure Method: "+stacktrace);
            }
        });
```

**Logcat**

```
2019-01-18 19:44:23.129 29583-29583/com.example.royta.retrofitdemo D/ROYs: onFailure Method: com.google.gson.JsonIOException: JSON document was not fully consumed.
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:41)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:223)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

**Sometime I'm getting this following Exception in the same code**

```
2019-01-18 21:55:39.610 1424-1424/com.example.royta.retrofitdemo D/ROYs: onFailure Method: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
        at okio.Okio$4.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:232)
        at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:285)
        at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:241)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:354)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:226)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:215)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:203)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:139)
        at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
        at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:354) 
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:226) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:215) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200) 
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: I would add a log interceptor to make sure that's really the JSON you're getting back.  Also, you can simplify your catch block:  `Log.e("ROYs", "onFailure Method", t);`

Comment: ```new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)``` add this interceptor to your okhttp client and see what logcat gives you when the server responds. This is likely a malformed json response given by your web server. Share the response with us to better see what  goes wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem I had when I received this error message "JSON document was not fully consumed" was simply that there was extraneous text at the end of the JSON String.

In my case I manually added text to the end of the valid JSON String to "test" error handling and retry logic on a Friday and then Monday forgot that I added this temporary code!

Answer (score 0):

You should put fields in model class in same order as in json

```
@SerializedName("isSend")
private boolean isSend;
@SerializedName("code")
private int code;
@SerializedName("email")
private boolean email;
```

Comment: It seems unlikely this would solve anything - unless you have a reference from Square indicating this is necessary.

Comment: As you said, I've checked it. Still getting com.google.gson.JsonIOException: JSON document was not fully consumed.

Answer (score 0):

If there are any null values for the keys then it throws **com.google.gson.JsonIOException:**

Eg :
{ **"request": null,** "body": "{"status": "passed","message": "[]"}" **"exception": null** }

Assign valid values for the keys